# How to set value to pandas crosstab?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I am just learning pandas, I do not know even possible to set values to a crosstab.
For example:
My data frame is:

```
data = [['Alice', 1, 2], ['Bob', 2, 5], ['Cameron', 3, 1],['Alice', 2, 5],['Bob', 3, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Music_id', 'Music_type'])
```

[The output of the data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRRb3.png)

Now apply crosstab on df:

```
ct = pd.crosstab([df.Name,df.Music_id],df.Music_type)
```

I got:
[The output of crosstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATcd2.png)

However, that is not what I expected.

I want it shows somehow like this:

| Music_id | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name |  |  |  |
| Alice | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| Bob | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| Cameron | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Basically, I want it instead of counting how many times the Name matches Music_id, it gives the relative value from the third column (Music_type). Did I use the right function to do that? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solutions to resolve :

**pd.crosstab**

```py
pd.crosstab(df['Name'], columns = df['Music_id'], values = df['Music_type'], aggfunc = 'first').fillna(0)

# Output :
# Music_id    1    2    3
# Name
# Alice     2.0  5.0  0.0
# Bob       0.0  5.0  1.0
# Cameron   0.0  0.0  1.0
```

**df.pivot**

```py
df.pivot(index = 'Name', columns = 'Music_id')['Music_type'].fillna(0)
# Output :
# Music_id    1    2    3
# Name
# Alice     2.0  5.0  0.0
# Bob       0.0  5.0  1.0
# Cameron   0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: That solves my question! Thank you very much! That is what I am exactly looking for!

Comment: Could you tell me what is that means aggfunc = 'first', what is the function of 'first'? Is that 'first' is pandas keyword?

Comment: @BohuaJia aggfunc = 'first' means we will get the first Music_type value for the Name and Music_id. If we had another record Name = 'Alice', 'Music_id = 1' and 'Music_type' = 7 would not appear in our table using aggfunc = 'first'.
List of aggfunc : https://datascientyst.com/list-aggregation-functions-aggfunc-groupby-pandas/

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the question even better!